# GCP: is it possible to switch IP for cloud functions instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've found many questions about whether it's possible to get static IP for GCP, but I would like the function to **switch IP as frequently as possible**.

The function is used to check whether there's any update on a site. But the site blocks IP that access too frequently. (> 60 accesses per min, I think)

I tested cloud function's IP addresses by creating a cloud function which simply logs it's current IP address. and triggered it with Pub/Sub messages. I published 100 messages, and all triggered function instances printed out same IP address.

Is there any way to make the function switch IP address?

Comment: Could I suggest you question your assumption that you *need* to check it for updates more than once per second? Trying to get around that rate limit does not sound like a great idea - would you be happy if someone tried to work around limits that you'd put in place? Suppose lots of other people try the same trick - how do you expect that would end?

Comment: @JonSkeet , You're right. In production ,the messages published to the pub/sub queue are separated with random intervals (mean=5), at most 200 messages per hour, so will the function instances triggered by the queue. I have confidence that the IP won't get blocked, but I need to be more sure. Switching IP is just a plan B.

Comment: I suspect it would be simpler to put your own rate limiting in, with something like a Firestore database that you can easily use to check when you last hit the site, and make sure you don't hit it too often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the function switch IP address?

No. Cloud Functions runs on Google servers. Those servers do not change IP addresses (at least not often enough for your purposes).

One strategy is to create a VPC connector from App Engine to your Project's VPC, setup a Cloud NAT with several IP addresses. However, even with that effort you will not be guaranteed "round robin" NAT IP addresses.

Another strategy is to create duplicate Cloud Functions in different regions and zones and then use one function to call another function in different regions and zones. Each cloud function in each zone will have a different public IP address.

Note: ***I do not endorse bypassing a vendors policies***. Your question has a technical challenge that applies to other use cases such as global health checks, distributed load creation, etc.